# What is the content of a Letter of Agreement between the Collaborative Decision Making participants?

Tags: air-traffic-control, usa, faa, emergency-procedures, atfm

1. Can you give a sample of a Letter of Agreement?
2. How to calculate average taxi time at airport?

Comment: Something like this: http://cdm.fly.faa.gov/wp-content/list_yo_files_user_folders/cdm_editor/cdm_doc/CDM%20MOA.docx ??

Comment: These appear to be two completely separate and only slightly related questions.  Should this be split into two different questions?

Answer (score 2):

First, a little bit about CDM and the participants that make up the team.  The [FAA's CDM Website](http://cdm.fly.faa.gov/) provides the following overview:

> Collaborative Decision Making (CDM) is a joint government/industry initiative aimed at improving air traffic flow management through increased information exchange among aviation community stakeholders. CDM is comprised of representatives from government, general aviation, airlines, private industry and academia who work together to create technological and procedural solutions to the Air Traffic Flow Management (ATFM) challenges faced by the National Airspace System (NAS).

This "team" of government/industry representatives is called the CDM Stakeholder's Group (CSG). There is a "Membership Agreement" that all parties of the CSG sign. This agreement outlines the roles and responsibilities of the FAA and each CSG member. It provides "rules" and processes for exchanging data and resolving disputes should any arise. It outlines the methods by which to modify the agreement, and how long the agreement should last.

A sample of the agreement letter that the FAA provides to each stakeholder member of the CSG is available to view here: http://cdm.fly.faa.gov/wp-content/list_yo_files_user_folders/cdm_editor/cdm_doc/CDM%20MOA.docx